# How to use URL parameter to set the default value of a radio button

Tags: reactjs, next.js

### The Goal

I'm building a two-sided marketplace for buyers and sellers. When someone navigates to my signup page, they could hit a URL like one of the following

- `/signup`
- `/signup?accountType=buyer`
- `/signup?accountType=seller`
- `/signup?accountType=asdfghjkl` (nonsensical, but possible)

My signup page has a radio button input where they choose Buyer or Seller.

[image: Buyer or Seller]

**Rules**

- The user must select one of these options.
- If the URL contains `accountType=buyer`, I would like to set the *default* selection as Buyer
- If the URL contains `accountType=seller`, I would like to set the *default* selection as Seller
- Even if a default option is selected, the user should be able to change it

---

### What I've tried

I am struggling to make this work with Next.js and [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/). Here's what I've tried.

```
// Fields.jsx

import { forwardRef } from 'react'

function Label({ id, children }) {
  return (
    <label htmlFor={id}>
      {children}
    </label>
  )
}

export const RadioFieldWithRef = forwardRef(function RadioField({ id, label, options, name, className = '', ...props }, ref) {
  return (
    <div className={className}>
      {label && <Label id={id}>{label}</Label>}
      <div>
        {options.map((option) => (
          <div className="flex items-center" key={option.value}>
            <input
              id={option.value}
              name={name}
              type="radio"
              value={option.value}
              defaultChecked={option.defaultChecked}
              ref={ref}
              {...props}
            />
            <label htmlFor={option.value}>
              {option.label}
            </label>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
})
```

```
// signup.jsx

import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { RadioFieldWithRef } from '@/components/Fields'
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function Signup() {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { accountType } = router.query
  
  // Email & Password Sign Up Form
  const { register } = useForm();
  const accountTypeField = register("account_type", {
    required: "Must select account type"
  })

  return (
        <form>
          <RadioFieldWithRef
            label="I'm a ..."
            name="account_type"
            options={ [
              {
                label: 'Buyer',
                value: 'buyer',
                defaultChecked: accountType === "buyer"
              },
              {
                label: 'Seller',
                value: 'seller',
                defaultChecked: accountType === "seller"
              },
            ] }
            {...accountTypeField}
          />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
  )
}
```

#### The Problem

When I try a URL like `/signup?accountType=buyer`, the default selection is not being set. I think this is because `router.query` is actually undefined on the first render. `console.log("accountType", accountType)` shows `undefined` before it eventually shows `buyer`. But I'm not sure how to overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

Change:
`const { accountType } = router.query`

To: `const [accountType, setAccountType] = useState('')`

And add this:

```
useEffect(() => {
if (router.query) { setAccountType(router.query.accountType) }
}, [router.query])
```

You're right that the problem is because the params aren't loaded in time to set the accountType, so you can use the useEffect hook to only set the accountType constant once the router.query is available.

Comment: I tried this as well and it does not work.

Comment: To elaborate, I think this doesn't work because react-hook-form uses uncontrolled components. From the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values), it states "Changing the value of `defaultValue` attribute after a component has mounted will not cause any update of the value in the DOM."

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the values like so?

```
const { register } = useForm({values: {
   "account_type": accountType
}});
```

My suggestion is to move the form in a different component, and only show it after the `router.isReady` is true. See https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#router-object for how to use the `isReady` flag.

Answer (score 0):

Got this to work with some help from leapful on [GitHub](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/discussions/9887#discussioncomment-4900554).

> You need to watch on change of `router.query` by using `useEffect` hook then use `setValue()` method from `useForm()` hook to set value for field account_type.

Here's what my resulting code looks like

```
// Fields.jsx

import { forwardRef } from 'react'

function Label({ id, children }) {
  return (
    <label htmlFor={id}>
      {children}
    </label>
  )
}

export const RadioFieldWithRef = forwardRef(function RadioField({ id, label, options, name, className = '', ...props }, ref) {
  return (
    <div className={className}>
      {label && <Label id={id}>{label}</Label>}
      <div>
        {options.map((option) => (
          <div className="flex items-center" key={option.value}>
            <input
              id={option.value}
              name={name}
              type="radio"
              value={option.value}
              ref={ref}
              {...props}
            />
            <label htmlFor={option.value}>
              {option.label}
            </label>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
})
```

```
// signup.jsx

import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { RadioFieldWithRef } from '@/components/Fields'
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function Signup() {
  const router = useRouter()
  
  // Email & Password Sign Up Form
  const { register, setValue } = useForm();
  const accountTypeField = register("account_type", {
    required: "Must select account type"
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    if(router.query?.accountType === "buyer" || router.query?.accountType === "seller"){
      setValue("account_type", router.query.accountType)
    }
  }, [router.query])

  return (
        <form>
          <RadioFieldWithRef
            label="I'm a ..."
            name="account_type"
            options={ [
              {
                label: 'Buyer',
                value: 'buyer',
              },
              {
                label: 'Seller',
                value: 'seller',
              },
            ] }
            {...accountTypeField}
          />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
  )
}
```